# Is it secure enough to use Digest HTTP Authentication combined with SSL encryption?

Tags: http, authentication, https, basic-authentication, digest-authentication

I am designing a mobile application which is supposed to interact with a remote server through the **HTTPS** protocol. This means that the system will manage to encrypt messages and keep the communication confidential by using a **SSL** certificate.

Well, I would like also to provide an authentication method in order to protect the system from external attacks and make it accesible only by users with valid credentials.
I'm now wondering if *Digest HTTP Authentication* (http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) could be a good idea or not.
I guess so, especially because I think there should be no particular risk since that way I should manage to combine encryption and authentication.

However, I've read somewhere that if I use SSL, HTTP basic authentication is secure enough. Is that true? What do you guys think about that?

Do you guys by chance have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If there's a high risk of a replay attack, Digest Auth is your friend. I recommend reading http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc2617.pdf

Comment: Hi Ariel, you are probably right. That's what I imagined. Thanks!!